# Design of audio playback system

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator

I'm having trouble understanding some concepts:

In a complete audio playback system the out put of the DAC is connected directly to the input of the low-pass filter, and the output of the low-pass filter is connected directly to the input of the volume control stage. Thus, the filter loads the converter, and the amplifier loads the filter.

So now I can't understand as to why this loading could be ignored. Meaning, why the converter, filter and volume control stage can be each analysed and designed in isolation?

Comment: Please simplify your questions. Right now you have a mix of questions embedded in one sentence, which could have your questions put on HOLD until you clean up your last paragraph and ask implicit item by item questions with a (?) symbol.

Comment: My question is why we can separately design and analyse each stage?

Comment: How do engineers design, build, test, and combine each stage is beyond the scope of this forum. The answers would fill up a book, and there are already books with these details. Look at the "Related" column to the right for previous answers.

Comment: Why do you think the interaction is ignored? In a specific circuit, that is very unlikely. Why do you think the stages are designed in isolation? That is nearly impossible. Your premises don't make sense, and so your questions don't make sense.

Comment: @Sparky256, can you farther explain so i'll have a better understanding of the situation?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to understand about the trailing end of the audio ADC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is simplified by the use of op-amps. By using ideal op-amp, we can see that the output of each stage is independent to that of the previous stage. This means, the output current is the same, regardless of the current being supplied. This also means that the op-amp in the Digital-To-Analog Converter has the same output, regardless of the amount of current that the Low-Pass Filter draws. Similarly, the op-amp in the Low-Pass Filter and the op-amp in the Volume Controller maintain the same output current, regardless of the current that is drawn.